# Frame animation problems android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am stuck showing frame animation in android. My problem is that I have to animate 36 images. The smallest image is 69 kb in size and the biggest(last frame) is 526kb. A total of 11mb. I know its insane but I need to do it. See images below. The app is already made for iphone and I have to port it to android.
Requirements:

1. smooth animation
2. no frame loss
3. consistent with iphone

The solutions I tried are:

1. AnimationDrawable by providing  in xml files. Problems: the start time is almost 6 -12 seconds. Images lose frames so jaggy experience.
2. Change imageview bitmap inside a handler. Problems: Frame loss and Out of memory
3. Create a custom imageview class. Define a method showAnimation() and inside it update bitmap and invalidate() the view unitl the last frame. Problems: Not fitting my requirement. This by far gave the best result but not half as required.

I am a noob in opengl and gamedevelopment. I am unable to find any alternative to my problem. Please help.

Smallest image:
[image]

Last image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can visualize the effect you are aiming at.I guess doing this will require pushing in different images onto the same imageView, with incremental frame rate.|

The accuracy will depend on the number of images you have. Greater the number of images finer will be the precision.

Also you need to implement incremental frame rate. So that it gives a smoother feel.

Doing this should be possible using a simple loop to change the image resource of the imageView Controller. There must be lag between two iterations, this lag will actually be the frame rate.

I think this can give satisfactory results.

Going for openGL, however, you will not need all these images. It will just require one image of the card that will be animated and duplicated to create the final image. This however is a complex piece of task(I think) so if you are catching some dead lines, you must go for a non-openGL solution like the 1st one, I have suggested.