# Error inflating class fragment, google maps api v2

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am testing a tutorial and I have the following error. Already tried everything but nothing seems to work. What's the problem, please help me!

```
    06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:317)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    ... 11 more
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.ip(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
06-19 16:05:20.369: E/AndroidRuntime(20022):    ... 21 more
```

This is my Main Activity

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    // GoogleMap
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    // Spinner in which the location types are stored
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;

    // A button to find the near by places
    Button mBtnFind=null;

    // Stores near by places
    Place[] mPlaces = null;

    // A String array containing place types sent to Google Place service
    String[] mPlaceType=null;

    // A String array containing place types displayed to user
    String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

    // The location at which user touches the Google Map
    LatLng mLocation=null;

    // Links marker id and place object
    HashMap<String, Place> mHMReference = new HashMap<String, Place>();

    // Specifies the drawMarker() to draw the marker with default color
    private static final float UNDEFINED_COLOR = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner 
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);  

        // Getting reference to Find Button
        mBtnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);      

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Google Map
            mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   

            // Handling screen rotation
            if(savedInstanceState !=null) {

                // Removes all the existing links from marker id to place object
                mHMReference.clear();

                //If near by places are already saved
                if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("places")){

                    // Retrieving the array of place objects
                    mPlaces = (Place[]) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("places");

                    // Traversing through each near by place object
                    for(int i=0;i<mPlaces.length;i++){

                        // Getting latitude and longitude of the i-th place
                        LatLng point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mPlaces[i].mLat),
                                                  Double.parseDouble(mPlaces[i].mLng));

                        // Drawing the marker corresponding to the i-th place
                        Marker m = drawMarker(point,UNDEFINED_COLOR);

                        // Linkng i-th place and its marker id
                        mHMReference.put(m.getId(), mPlaces[i]);
                    }

                }

                // If a touched location is already saved
                if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("location")){

                    // Retrieving the touched location and setting in member variable
                    mLocation = (LatLng) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("location");

                    // Drawing a marker at the touched location
                    drawMarker(mLocation, BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);                                       
                }
            }       


            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            mBtnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                   

                    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];

                    mGoogleMap.clear();


                    if(mLocation==null){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please mark a location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;                     
                    }

                    drawMarker(mLocation, BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);                                       

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+mLocation.latitude+","+mLocation.longitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyAP6ZS07phmDZNurSCHZFz7o7jAXL3bmcU");


                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
                }
            });

            // Map Click listener
            mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Clears all the existing markers 
                    mGoogleMap.clear();

                    // Setting the touched location in member variable
                    mLocation = point;

                    // Drawing a marker at the touched location
                    drawMarker(mLocation,BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);

                }
            });         

            // Marker click listener
            mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                    // If touched at User input location
                    if(!mHMReference.containsKey(marker.getId()))
                        return false;           

                    // Getting place object corresponding to the currently clicked Marker
                    Place place = mHMReference.get(marker.getId());

                    // Creating an instance of DisplayMetrics
                    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

                    // Getting the screen display metrics
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

                    // Creating a dialog fragment to display the photo
                    PlaceDialogFragment dialogFragment = new PlaceDialogFragment(place,dm);                 

                    // Getting a reference to Fragment Manager
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                    // Starting Fragment Transaction
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                    // Adding the dialog fragment to the transaction
                    ft.add(dialogFragment, "TAG");

                    // Committing the fragment transaction
                    ft.commit();

                    return false;
                }
            });     
        }           
    }   

    /**
     * A callback function, executed on screen rotation
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        // Saving all the near by places objects
        if(mPlaces!=null)
            outState.putParcelableArray("places", mPlaces);

        // Saving the touched location
        if(mLocation!=null)
            outState.putParcelable("location", mLocation);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    /** A method to download json data from argument url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);                


                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();                

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }         


    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                Log.d("URL:",url[0]);
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();           

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of ParserTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Place[]>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected Place[] doInBackground(String... jsonData) {  


            Place[] places = null;
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);              
                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Place[] places){               

            mPlaces = places;

            for(int i=0;i< places.length  ;i++){

                Place place = places[i];    

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(place.mLat);                

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(place.mLng);

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);            

                Marker m = drawMarker(latLng,UNDEFINED_COLOR);           

                // Adding place reference to HashMap with marker id as HashMap key
                // to get its reference in infowindow click event listener
                mHMReference.put(m.getId(), place);

            }
        }   

    }

    /**
     * Drawing marker at latLng with color
     */
    private Marker drawMarker(LatLng latLng,float color){
        // Creating a marker
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();              

        // Setting the position for the marker
        markerOptions.position(latLng);

        if(color != UNDEFINED_COLOR)
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(color));

        // Placing a marker on the touched position
        Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        return m;     

    }           


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearbyplacesphotos.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDvgL4OuzGbtXcDXD9k8VXey7XNUvFaoqM"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my layout file: activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_find"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"            
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
                android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

    <fragment 
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from your logcat and your manifest file you are missing this line as a direct child of application tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: @IA already asked question so better to flag as _Duplicate_.

Comment: I get that you want to flag this question as a but what what is that about @IA already asked question. P.S. i am not a native english speaker. Can you look at my question here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306063/frame-animation-problems-android and sorry for the trouble